# FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key) during Netlify deployment

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, netlify

I am building a Next.js application and using Firebase Auth for client authentication. I am using Netlify for my hosting.

**firebaseConfig.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

The below code verifies ID tokens and makes use of the "[firebase-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin)" library.

**firebaseAdmin.js**

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./secrets.json");

export const verifyIdToken = (token) => {
    if (!admin.apps.length){
        admin.initializeApp({
            credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
        })
    }
    return admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token).catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

Below code manages global user state and sets cookies.

**auth.js**

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react"
import { onIdTokenChanged } from "firebase/auth"
import {auth} from './firebaseConfig'
import nookies from 'nookies'

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        return(onIdTokenChanged(auth, async (user) => {
                if(!user){
                    setUser(null);
                    nookies.set(undefined,"token", "", {});
                    return
                }
                const token = await user.getIdToken(true);
                setUser(user);
                nookies.set(undefined,"token", token, {});
        }))
    },[]);

    return(<AuthContext.Provider value={{user}}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>);
}

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

This setup gives no errors during development.

However, during deployment, I get the following error in Netlify dashboard:

```
7:25:04 AM: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).
7:25:04 AM:     at createErrorInternal (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-1491e429.js:467:40)
7:25:04 AM:     at _assert (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-1491e429.js:471:15)
7:25:04 AM:     at file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-1491e429.js:6075:13
7:25:04 AM:     at Component.instanceFactory (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-1491e429.js:6092:11)
7:25:04 AM:     at Provider.getOrInitializeService (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:290:39)
7:25:04 AM:     at Provider.initialize (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:234:31)
7:25:04 AM:     at initializeAuth (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-1491e429.js:585:27)
7:25:04 AM:     at getAuth (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-1491e429.js:6141:18)
7:25:04 AM:     at /opt/build/repo/.next/server/chunks/373.js:82:68 {
7:25:04 AM:   code: 'auth/invalid-api-key',
7:25:04 AM:   customData: { appName: '[DEFAULT]' }
7:25:04 AM: }
7:25:04 AM: > Build error occurred
7:25:04 AM: Error: Failed to collect page data for /
7:25:04 AM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:949:15 {
7:25:04 AM:   type: 'Error'
7:25:04 AM: }
```

My .env.local file contains the proper values for Firebase. I don't know what is causing the error.

Comment: Are you sure you have added the environment variables in Netlify UI? You mention your `.env.local` has the values, but that file would most likely by not pushed to your git repo, for Netlify to be able to access those variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably occurs because the Netlify does not know about your environment variables during the build time of the deployment. You have to add those environment variables declared in the .env.local to Netlify as well. Go to the Build & Deploy settings in your Netlify Site Settings, and then add your values to the "Environment variables" section.